# Bit shifting zero byte

Tags: processing, bit

I write my program in Processing, but I think it's not only this language problem. Code:

```
long combine8(int array[]) {
 long result = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
   byte byteval = (byte)array[i];
   result |= (byteval<<(8*i));
 }
 return result;
}
```

This function combines 8 bytes to one long value. Works normally until one of array values is zero. It just ignores it. For example:

```
Array value: 1 binary 00000001  
Array value: 0 binary 00000000 
Array value: 0 binary 00000000 
Array value: 0 binary 00000000 
Array value: 0 binary 00000000
Array value: 160 binary 10100000 
Array value: 255 binary 11111111
Array value: 25 binary 00011001 
Result: 11111111111111111010000000000001
```

Result value is cut due to parsing long to int for displaying in decimal, but that has no matter, it's enough to see first 16 bits. It ignored zero array values and wrote 160 after 1.
Is there a way to apply those zeros to result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess: Try casting your byte to long first:

```
result |= (((long)byteval)<<(8*i));
```

Or simply avoid casting `array[i]` to `byte` at the beginning.

Comment: Wild, but worked! After I deleted casting to byte and casted array element to long it worked. Thanks!